# Slope of phase function

Tags: linear-systems, phase, transfer-function, linear-phase, group-delay

Would appreciate some help understanding if I take the phase function of some transfer function and derivative it in the linear part of it which is around the resonant frequency what does this slope means. basically what I don't get is what is the meaning or the importance of that slope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The negative derivative of the phase with respect to frequency is the [group delay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_delay_and_phase_delay). There are many posts on this site that deal with questions concerning group delay.

In short, when a bandpass signal with center frequency $f_0$ is passed through a linear and time-invariant system, the delay of the signal's envelope is (approximately) given by the system's group delay evaluated at frequency $f_0$.